# Xamarin Forms BindableProperty creation throws TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

I have a problem with creating BindableProperty in my user control. My user control is a class ResultLabel. This is my code, where I'm creating BindableProperty:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty StateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(State), typeof(ResultStateEnum), typeof(ResultLabel));
```

This BindableProperty supposed to accept Enumeration (ResultStateEnum) but it throws `TypeInitializationException`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no default value parameter passed to that method. This is an optional parameter, so program will try to pass the null as a default parameter. Enumeration can't be null, so it will trigger an exception. You should add one more parameter to `Create` method. Let's say that `ResultStateEnum` has value `ResultStateEnum.Default`. Then your code should look like:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty StateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(State), typeof(ResultStateEnum), typeof(ResultLabel), ResultStateEnum.Default);
```